# Как подключиться к сетевому адаптеру другого устройства?

Tags: сеть, wifi

Каким образом можно подключиться с одной машины (назовем её comp1) к сетевому адаптеру другой машины (comp2), находящейся другой сети?
Под "подключиться" я подразумеваю, что comp1 будет видеть сетевой адаптер comp2 как свой и сможет, например, просканировать сеть, в которой находится comp2

В идеале, хочу с мобильного устройства (в данном случае comp2), использовать какой-нибудь airodump-ng (который будет находится на моем домашнем сервере (comp1) и получать собственно сам трафик с сетевой карты мобилки)

За помощь реально буду сердечно благодарен до конца жизни

Comment: Ssh remote capture

Comment: Хотя я вот писал програмку на си которая трафик захватывает и сразу отправляет